# I have problems with the delete method in Mockito

Tags: testing, mockito, spring-tool-suite, delete-method

```
public class BookControllerTest {
    int ID=2;
    int RELEASE=22;
    String AUTHOR="HOMERO";
    String TITLE="LA ODISEA";
    Book BOOK = new Book();
    Optional<Book> OPTIONAL_BOOK = Optional.of(BOOK);
    List<Review>REVIEW_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
    Optional<Book> OPTIONAL_BOOK_EMPTY = Optional.empty();
    /*Optional<Book> OPTIONAL_BOOK_DELETE = Optional.deleted();->error*/
    
    @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private BookController bookController;
        
    ...

    @Test
    public void testDeleteBook() {
        Mockito.when(bookRepository.findById(ID)).thenReturn(OPTIONAL_BOOK_DELETE);
        ResponseEntity<Object> httpresponse = bookController.deleteBook(ID);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, httpresponse.getStatusCode());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testDeleteBookNotFound() {
        Mockito.when(bookRepository.findById(ID)).thenReturn(OPTIONAL_BOOK_EMPTY);
        ResponseEntity<Object> httpresponse = bookController.deleteBook(ID);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, httpresponse.getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

I am new to this, would you be very kind, where is the error or what is the correct way?, I thought I could do the same as the empty method but I tried all the reserved words but it didn't work for me

Comment: What is `Optional.deleted()`?

Answer (score 0):

[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is a SDK class introduced with Java 8 and defines a fixed set of methods (cf. JavaDoc). You cannot "invent" your own methods on it and expect them to magically work. `java.util.Optional` is in no way dependent on your services.

If you have an optional without value, that's `Optional.empty()`. If you have an optional *with* a value, that's `Optional.of(…)`. So deleting a book would still use `Optional.empty()`. Same as your `bookNotFound` test uses `Optional.empty()` and not `Optional.notFound()`.

(Answer too long for a comment, but I'd rather have this question closed as "typo".)